# What is the mistake in this Java Code?

Tags: java

The 'ans' string contains "55/42=" (assumption). I am trying calculate the answer of this string and store it in 'ans' itself. Please point out my mistakes in the code.

```
public void equalto() {
    int i, j, ltemp2;
    String temp1 = "", temp2 = "", temp2rev = "", temp3 = "";
    char temp;
    double temp11, temp22, temp33;
    for (i = 0; ans.charAt(i) != '='; i++) {
        if (ans.charAt(i) == '/') {
            j = i + 1;
            while (ans.charAt(j) != '+' || ans.charAt(j) != '-' || ans.charAt(j) != '*' || ans.charAt(j) != '/' || ans.charAt(j) != '=') {
                temp = ans.charAt(j);
                temp1 = temp1 + temp;
                j++;
            }
            j = i - 1;
            while ((j >= 0) && (ans.charAt(j) != '+' || ans.charAt(j) != '-' || ans.charAt(j) != '*' || ans.charAt(j) != '/')) {
                temp = ans.charAt(j);
                temp2 = temp2 + temp;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    ltemp2 = temp2.length();   //For reversing the temp2
    for (j = ltemp2 - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        temp2rev = temp2rev + temp2.charAt(j);
    temp11 = Double.parseDouble(temp1);
    temp22 = Double.parseDouble(temp2rev);   //temp2rev is the actual string. temp2 is in the reversed form.
    temp33 = temp22 / temp11;
    temp3 = String.valueOf(temp33);
    ans = ans.replaceFirst(temp2rev + "/" + temp1 + "=", temp3);
}
```

Comment: What makes you think there is a mistake in the code?  Do you get errors trying to compile or run it?  If so, what are they?  If it runs without error, does the output differ from what you expected?  If so, what was the expected output?  What was the actual output?  When asking questions about why your code doesn't work, it is important to explain **exactly** what the problem is.

Comment: I tried to run it on Ideone. I got a runtime error. When my input was "55/42=", the error was "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6"

Comment: the expected output is the answer of 55/42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(ans.charAt(j)!='+' || ...
while((j>=0)&&(ans.charAt(j)!='+' || ...
```

replace all || with &&

```
temp2=temp2+temp;
```

to get a correct temp2 directly, you could do

```
temp2 = temp + temp2;
```